# Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#-4.0, inheritance

I get an error stating "Products does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" from the following code:

```
public class Products
{
    string id;
    string name;
    double price;
    int soldCount;
    int stockCount;

    public Products(string id, string name, double price, 
                      int soldCount, int stockCount, double tax)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.soldCount = soldCount;
        this.stockCount = stockCount;
    }
}

//I have got some get and set values for the code above 
//but it would have been too long to put in here

public class FoodProducts : Products
{
    public FoodProduct()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is food product");
    }

    public void Limit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an Attribute of a Product");
    }
}
```

Comment: The usual naming convention for classes are singular, not plural (e.g. `Product` instead of `Products`), since a class defines a type, that then can be instantiated. Whether you will have more of them or not should not be apart of the naming convention.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Error : Parent does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230544/c-sharp-error-parent-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments)

Answer (score 119):

Several rules about C# come into play here:

1. Each class must have a constructor (In order to be, well constructed)
2. If you do not provide a constructor, a constructor will be provided for you, free of change, automatically by the compiler.

   This means that the class

   ```
   class Demo{}
   ```

   upon compilation is provided with an empty constructor, becoming

   ```
   class Demo{
      public Demo(){}
   }
   ```

   and I can do

   ```
   Demo instance = new Demo();
   ```
3. If you do provide a constructor (any constructor with any signature), the empty constructor will not be generated

   ```
   class Demo{
      public Demo(int parameter){}
   }

   Demo instance = new Demo(); //this code now fails
   Demo instance = new Demo(3); //this code now succeeds
   ```

   This can seem a bit counter-intuitive, because adding code seems to break existing unrelated code, but it's a design decision of the C# team, and we have to live with it.
4. When you call a constructor of a derived class, if you do not specify a base class constructor to be called, the compiler calls the empty base class constructor, so

   ```
   class Derived:Base {
      public Derived(){}
   }
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   class Derived:Base {
      public Derived() : base() {}
   }
   ```

So, in order to construct your derived class, you must have a parameterless constructor on the base class. Seeing how you added a constructor to the Products, and the compiler did not generate the default constructor, you need to explicitly add it in your code, like:

```
public Products()
{
}
```

or explicitly call it from the derived constructor

```
public FoodProduct()
       : base(string.Empty, string.Empty, 0, 0, 0, 0)
{
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Since `Products` has no constructor that takes 0 arguments, you must create a constructor for `FoodProducts` that calls the constructor of `Products` will all the required arguments.

In C#, this is done like the following:

```
public class FoodProducts : Products
{

    public FoodProducts(string id, string name, double price, int soldCount, int stockCount, double tax)   
    : base(id, name, price, soldCount, stockCount, tax)
    {
    }

    public void Limit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is an Attribute of a Product");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add this constructor to `FoodProducts`, you can also create a constructor with no parameter to `Products`.

Answer (score 8):

the constructor of the inherited class needs to construct the base class first. since the base class does not have a default constructor (taking 0 arguments) and you are not using the non-default constructor you have now, this won't work. so either A) add a default constructor to your base class, in which case the code of the descending class needs no change; or B) call the non-default constructor of the base class from the constructor of the descending class, in which case the base class needs no change.

A

```
public class Products
{
    public Products() { }
}

public class FoodProducts : Products
{
    public FoodProducts() { }
}
```

B

```
public class Products
{
    public class Products(args) { }
}

public class FoodProducts : Products
{
    public FoodProducts(args) : base(args) { }
}
```

some of this is explained rather OK on msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228387%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: +1: I just encountered the same error: "[class] does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments".  The problem was that the base class and every subclass had a constructor defined.  The solution was to make sure each subclass called ": base (...)" to initialize the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

As you inherit from `Products`, you must call a base construct of `Products` in your own class.

You didn't write`:base(id, name, ....)` so C# assumes you call the default parameterless constructor, but it doesn't exist.

Create a default parameterless constructor for `Products`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
public Products()
{

}
```

in your products class And you will not get error

**Reason:**
There exists a default constructor with 0 parameter for every class. So no need to define/write it explicitly (by programmer) BUT when you overload a default constructor with your desired number and type of parameters then it becomes a compulsion to define the default constructor yourself (explicitly) along with your overloaded constructor