# child class gives error about parent class constructor

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138221/does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments)

I have a DAL class called getData with a constructor that forces you to pass the connection string:

```
namespace AQProduct
{
  public class getData
  {
    public getData(string strConnectionString)
    {
    }
  }
 }
```

I have classes that do the actual work:

```
namespace AQProduct
{
  public class User_DL : getData
  {
  }
}
```

Build fails with

> 'AQProduct.getData' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments

How do I get this to work?

Comment: `string strConnectionString` ? `class getData` ? They are perfectly *legal*, but they aren't exactly standard naming conventions in C# or .NET; you might want to consider more idiomatic naming.

Comment: @Mark: your suggestions?

Comment: `connectionString` and possibly `DataRetriever` or `DaoBase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a (non-static) class, if you don't add a constructor of your own, one is implicitly created of the form:

```
public ClassName : base() { }
```

i.e. call the base-class's parameterless constructor. Since that *doesn't exist*, you will **need** to add a custom constructor, for example:

```
public User_DL() : base("some fixed value from somewhere") {}
```

or:

```
public User_DL(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {}
```

Comment: @mark: your suggestions re: naming conventions?

Comment: @callisto pretty much: what Daniel said

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a constructor to the derived class and pass the connection string to the base class:

```
public class User_DL : getData
{
    public User_DL(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default constructor in your DAL class:

```
// Your default constructor
public getData()
{
}
```

Or add the constructor with params to your derived class; go with:

```
public class User_DL : getData
{
    public User_DL(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
       // Insert code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this constructor

```
public User_DL(string yourConnection) : base(yourConnection)
{


}
```