# how to prevent base constructor to be called when a child is instantiated?

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance

How can I prevent a base constructor to be called when a child is instantiated?
I'm coding in C# WPF with three levels of inheritance as follow:

SonClass -> FatherClass -> GrandFatherClass

Once I instantiate from the SonClass, the constructor of the FatherClass and GrandFatherClass are automatically called, is there a wat to prevent it or changing the order from bottom-up instead of top-down?

Comment: I think your constructors may be doing too much.

Comment: base *(father)* constructor will always execute when creating an instance of child class, you can pass a parameter in the base class constructor to *not* execute some code in base class constructor, but you can't restrict execution of the base class constructor.

Comment: Take a look at the following question and answer for some rules about class's constructors in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138221/does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments/12138707#12138707

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You **cannot** do this.

By definition, when a derived object is created, the base class's constructor is run as well.

You can specify *which* base class constructor is run:

```
public MyDerivedClass() : base() //Or some args to pick an overload
```

But you cannot prevent it from being called. The fact that this is a problem implies that you are doing to much in the constructor. The constructor should **only** be used for initializing member variables and simple initialization logic. Any long running operations or complex logic should be in other methods.

Such logic is commonly put into a `virtual` "Init" method, so that derived classes can override the initialization behavior.

Comment: Thanks , virtual keyword helped ;)