# Class does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I have these 2 classes that are respectively called: **Malicious** and **MaliciousSmall**:

Code of **Malicious**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataModel.MaliciousCode
{
    public class Malicious : MaliciousSmall
    {
    }
}
```

Code of **MaliciousSmall**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;
namespace DataModel.MaliciousCode
{
    public class MaliciousSmall
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int MaliciousCodeAlertId { get; set; }
        public string SourceId { get; set; }
        public int MalCodeID { get; set; }
        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        ......................................................

        // CONSTRUCTOR:

       public MaliciousSmall(DataRow row)
        {
            Id = int.Parse(row["Id"].ToString());

            MaliciousCodeAlertId = (row["MaliciousCodeAlertId"] is DBNull) ? MaliciousCodeAlertId = -1 : MaliciousCodeAlertId = int.Parse(row["MaliciousCodeAlertId"].ToString());
            SourceId = (row["SourceId"] is DBNull) ? SourceId = "" : SourceId = row["MaliciousCodeAlertId"].ToString();
            MalCodeID = (row["MalCodeID"] is DBNull) ? MalCodeID = -1 : MalCodeID = int.Parse(row["MalCodeID"].ToString());
            Title = (row["Title"] is DBNull) ? Title = "" : Title = row["Title"].ToString();

        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        ......................................................
        }

}
```

My problem is that, after that I have implementet the **MaliciousSmall** class I obtain the following error on the **Malicious** constructor:

> Error 53  'DataModel.MaliciousCode.MaliciousSmall' does not contain a
>   constructor that takes 0
>   arguments C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\DataModel\MaliciousCode\Malicious.cs    9   18  DataModel

What can I do to solve it?

I tried to create an empty constructor that take a **DataRow** object as paramether, something like it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data;

namespace DataModel.MaliciousCode
{
    public class Malicious : MaliciousSmall
    {

        public Malicious(DataRow row)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But I still have the same problem. What am I missing? What can I do to solve?

Comment: you need to add a constructor that takes no row:

public Malicious()
        {

        }

Comment: @GoranŠtuc: No, that won't work. Look at the inheritance.

Comment: Actually, this questions have been answered many times here on SO: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230544/c-sharp-error-parent-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138221/does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580168/c-sharp-inheritance-issue-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-argument). Next time, search first, please.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The error is telling you that the `Malicious` constructor can't find a suitable constructor to chain to in its base class (`MaliciousSmall`).

The initial problem is that your derived class constructor implicitly contains this constructor:

```
public Malicious() : base()
{
}
```

Or even when you've added an explicit constructor, it's still trying to chain to a parameterless one:

```
public Malicious(DataRow row) : base()
{
}
```

... but there *is* no such parameterless constructor in the base class (`MaliciousSmall`), hence the error.

I think you want to chain to the constructor taking a row (the one you *have* declared in `MaliciousSmall`):

```
public Malicious(DataRow row) : base(row)
{
}
```

That's assuming you *always* want a row to be provided to the constructor. If you actually want to allow an instance to be created without specifying a row, then you need to add a parameterless constructor to the *base* class:

```
public MaliciousSmall()
{
    // Set fields/properties to some default values
}
```

You'd probably then want your derived class to have two constructors:

```
public Malicious() // Implicitly chain to the parameterless base constructor
{
}

public Malicious(DataRow row) : base(row) // Chain to parameterized constructor
{
}
```

See my [article on constructor chaining](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more details.

Comment: So what are you saying to me is that doing public Malicious(DataRow row) : base(row) I am executing the override of the MaliciousSmall constructor that in my Malicious constructor?

Comment: @AndreaNobili: Constructors aren't virtual - you don't *override* them. However, each constructor needs to *chain* to either another constructor in the same class, or a constructor in the base class - that chained constructor is executed before the body of the constructor which is doing the chaining. That code chains from the `Malicious(DataRow)` constructor to the `MaliciousSmall(DataRow)` constructor. Read the article I've linked to at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @AndreaNobili , it's worthwhile to read Jon Skeets article on how constructors work if you are going to do C# programming. He mentioned it briefly below his answer: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html

Comment: Ok, perfect, tnx so much, now I will also read your artigle

Comment: Holy cow, why so... strange, I would say, rules of constructor chaining? It looks like the whole problem is that .NET is too lazy to generate a default constructor!

Comment: @hijarian Not at all. If you explicitly write a non-default constructor, generating a default constructor would be *exactly the wrong thing to do*. It would let any consumer of your class completely bypass the invariants you've attempted to put in place.

Answer (score 7):

> I tried to create an empty constructor that take a DataRow object as parameter

I think you have the term **empty** confused. An empty constructor accepts no parameters by definition. You cannot have an empty constructor with parameters.

If you'd like to keep the parameter in the derived class's constructor too, you need to use the [`base`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword to specify the base constructor.

```
public Malicious(DataRow row)
    : base(row)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You class `Malicious` has not defined any constructor at all, and from the [MSDN docs for Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

> Unless the class is static, **classes without constructors are given a
>   public default constructor** by the C# compiler in order to enable
>   class instantiation.

That means your class has:

```
public class Malicious : MaliciousSmall
{
   public Malicious()
   {
   }
}
```

From the [same MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

> In a derived class, if a base-class constructor is not called
>   explicitly by using the `base` keyword, the default constructor, if
>   there is one, is called **implicitly**.

That effectively means:

```
   public Malicious() :base() //implicitly calling base class constructor
```

Since your base class doesn't have a default constructor **(one with no parameter)** you get the error.

Now you have two options to fix that error.

1. Define a default constructor in your base class.
2. Explicitly call the base constructor from your derived class.

Probably for your situation it seems better to call the base constructor explicitly, since both the constructors are receiving same type parameter. 
You can do:

```
public Malicious(DataRow row) :base(row)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add a parameterless constructor, pass the `row` to the *base* class constructor:

```
public Malicious(DataRow row):base(row)
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are deriving any class from base class then you should either add parameterless constructor in base class or spefify a base class constructor to be called at derived class.
So in order to solve your issue:
Solution 1: Add parameterless constructor in base class i.e. at MaliciousSmall as,

```
public MaliciousSmall()
{
}
```

Solution 2: Specify base class constructor at derived class constructor as,

```
public DataRow row;
public Malicious: base(row)
{
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

If there are no constructors defined in the class the compiler provides a default/parameterless constructor which is used to instantiate its corresponding objects as shown below.

```
class MaliciousSmall
{
    //if no constructors are defined then compiler adds the following
    //public MaliciousSmall()
}

class Malicious: MaliciousSmall
{
    //if no constructors are defined then compiler adds the following
    //public Malicious() : base()
}

Malicious obj = new Malicious();
```

Since you have defined a constructor in the base class the compiler assumes that you do not require a default/parameterless constructor. When the default constructor of `MaliciousSmall` tries to call the default constructor of its base class the constructor chaining breaks.

```
class MaliciousSmall
{
    public MaliciousSmall(DataRow row)
    {
        //compiler will not supply a default constructor
    }
}

class Malicious: MaliciousSmall
{
    //if no constructors are defined then compiler adds the following
    //public Malicious() : base()
}

Malicious obj = new Malicious();
```

The instantiation of the object requires the default constructor of the `Malicious` class to be called which in turn tries to call the default constructor of the base class, but since this doesn't exist, the constructor chaining breaks.

It is advised that we use the required constructors such that it doesn't cause the chaining to break.

```
class MaliciousSmall
{
    public MaliciousSmall()
    {
        //
    }

    public MaliciousSmall(DataRow row)
    {
        //
    }
}

class Malicious:MaliciousSmall
{
    public Malicious()
    {
        //
    }

    public Malicious(DataRow row):base(row)
    {
        //
    }
}

Malicious obj = new Malicious();
```

Constructors are very important since, I don't think your program gets anywhere without an object instantiation, please do make sure to visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx) and do take an effort to read about `this` keyword.