# Error in inheritance and constructors

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

I'm currently studying a program wherein inheritance and constructors are involved. I'm actually a newbie in C# so I'm just wondering why does this code below has an error on line 57, it says that loan does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. Please help me analyze what's wrong in it. Thank you very much.
using System;

```
class DemoCarLoan3
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Loan aLoan = new Loan(333, "Hanson", 7000.00);
CarLoan aCarLoan = new CarLoan(444, "Carlisle", 30000.00, 2011, "BMW");
        Console.WriteLine("Loan #{0} for {1} is for Php{2}",
        aLoan.LoanNumber, aLoan.LastName,
        aLoan.LoanAmount.ToString("0,000.00"));
        Console.WriteLine("Loan #{0} for {1} is for Php{2}",
aCarLoan.LoanNumber, aCarLoan.LastName,
aCarLoan.LoanAmount.ToString("0.00"));
        Console.WriteLine(" Loan #{0} is for a {1} {2}",
        aCarLoan.LoanNumber, aCarLoan.Year,
        aCarLoan.Make);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Loan
{
    public const double MINIMUM_LOAN = 5000;
    protected double loanAmount;
    public int LoanNumber { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double LoanAmount
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < MINIMUM_LOAN)
                loanAmount = MINIMUM_LOAN;
            else
                loanAmount = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return loanAmount;
        }
    }

    public Loan(int num, string name, double amount)
    {
        LoanNumber = num;
        LastName = name;
        LoanAmount = amount;
    }
}

class CarLoan : Loan
{
    private const int EARLIEST_YEAR = 2006;
    private const int LOWEST_INVALID_NUM = 1000;
    private int year;

    public CarLoan(int num, string name, double amount, int year, string make)
    {
        Year = year;
        Make = make;
    }

    public int Year
    {
        set
        {
            if (value < EARLIEST_YEAR)
            {
                year = value;
                loanAmount = 0;
            }
            else
                year = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return year;
        }
    }

    public string Make { get; set; }

    public new int LoanNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return base.LoanNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < LOWEST_INVALID_NUM)
                base.LoanNumber = value;
            else
                base.LoanNumber = value % LOWEST_INVALID_NUM;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230544/c-sharp-error-parent-does-not-contain-a-constructor-that-takes-0-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add call to the base constructor

```
public CarLoan(int num, string name, double amount, int year, string make) 
    : base(num, name, amount)
{
    Year = year;
    Make = make;
}
```

When you declare a constructor in a derived class which does not call to a base constructor, then it automatically calls a constructor with 0 parameters which does not exist there. If you take your code as is, it will compile to

```
public CarLoan(int num, string name, double amount, int year, string make) 
    : base()
{
    Year = year;
    Make = make;
}
```

But that's invalid since there is no constructor with 0 parameters in the base class. So either create one or call one of existing.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't declare a constructor, the C# compiler will generate a parameterless one. But when you declare a constructor that takes args, the C# compiler will not give you that default one so you have to write one.

```
 public Loan()
 {
 }
```

Comment: Oh I see that's why I need to declare a parameterless constructor. Another question, the code runs but in these lines `Console.WriteLine("Loan #{0} for {1} is for Php{2}", aCarLoan.LoanNumber, aCarLoan.LastName, aCarLoan.LoanAmount.ToString("0.00"));
        Console.WriteLine(" Loan #{0} is for a {1} {2}", aCarLoan.LoanNumber, aCarLoan.Year, aCarLoan.Make);` it doesn't display the aCarLoan.LoanNumber and the aCarLoan.LastName. Why is that so?

Comment: @user3103939 It was because when you created the `CarLoan` the parameterless empty constructor ran on the base class. The constructor where in the base class where the properties of `Loan` are set, did not run. So because of that, maybe in your case it was a bad idea to overload the constructor of `Loan`. It is fine for a class not to have the parameterless instance constructor; inheritors just have to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error, because your `Loan` class does not contain any Default Constructor. Default Constructor means, Constructor without any arugments(parameters).

As soon as you create a Parameterized Constructor in any class, Default Constructor is destroyed, so, you cannot create instance of this class like this:

```
  Loan obj = new Loan();
```

unless you create a Default Constructor(without any arguments)

create this also in your loan class

```
public Loan()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All classes in c# inherit from `Object` class,if you don't define a parameterless constructor,your class inherit a default parameterless constructor from `Object` class,but if you define a constructor which takes some arguments,default constructor will be ignored.So in this case you have to define a parameterless constructor:

```
public Loan()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to create a `CarLoan` object:

```
    CarLoan aCarLoan = new CarLoan(444, "Carlisle", 30000.00, 2011, "BMW");
```

invokes this constructor:

```
    public CarLoan(int num, string name, double amount, int year, string make)
    {
       ...
    }
```

What may not be obvious is that the `CarLoan` constructor is compiled as if you had written this:

```
    public CarLoan(int num, string name, double amount, int year, string make)
        : base()
    {
       ...
    }
```

When constructing derived objects, the base class constructor is invoked first automatically (even if you don't do it explicitly).  More generically, objects are constructed in top-down fashion, from the most base class to the most derived class.  Because you did not specify which `Loan` constructor to use, the compiler uses the parameterless constructor by default.  The solution is to either provide a parameterless constructor on the `Loan` class:

```
    public Loan()
    {
    }
```

The other option is to use the solution suggested by @Ondrej Janacek.